# Internet Explorer 11 only applying CSS after Ctrl+F5

Tags: css, internet-explorer

In Chrome and Firefox my site loads perfectly, however in Internet Explorer 11 the CSS is only applying fully after pressing Ctrl+F5 (sometimes several times). Strange thing is that some CSS IS applied. Just some elements are ignored.
Since my CSS is pretty large I don't want to paste it all here but the behavior can be seen live here http://www.telefonievergelijken.nl

Here's how it looks in Internet Explorer 11 on 1st pageload:

[image: IE]

And here in FireFox:

[image: FireFox]

Comment: Could be a caching thing

Comment: It is not a cache problem - the problem appears on browserstack.com

Comment: You'll have to do some mobile styling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your webpage:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

I believe it is a problem. [It tells browser to display page in IE8 compatibility view, so most things is displayed wrongly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: You should point to existing documentation so that the user can read to better understand what you are talking about. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: If this is the problem/answer (which it appears to be), then why is "Ctrl+F5 (sometimes several times)" apparently able to get around it?!